# How to fire the ajax request with same post parameter when browser back button is pressed?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I need to fire the ajax request with same post parameters when browser back button is pressed. any way to remember the query or either the page post parameter that was passed with the ajax fire before back button is pressed.

I search through web an found those methods

1. Use localsotrage (when the page unloads) or document.location.hash
2. Or use Cookie (Not prefered)

   ```
     window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
          if (('localStorage' in window) && window['localStorage'] !== null) {
             localStorage.setItem('myVar', $_POST['start']);
     }
    }


   if( isNaN(start)) {
     if (('localStorage' in window) && window['localStorage'] !== null) {
        if ('myVar' in localStorage || window.location.hash) {
           start = localStorage.getItem('myVar');
        } // Was Missing
    }  
   }
   ```

Comment: Have you tried `localStorage`? does it work for you?

Comment: Are you using hashes in your URL structure? http://jqueryfordesigners.com/enabling-the-back-button/

Comment: LocalStorgae seems to be working, but window.onunload not works, I am not able to console.log when the page leaves.

Answer (score 0):

you can try [uriAnchor plugin](https://github.com/mmikowski/urianchor)

It provides the capability to make the URI fragment your application state API. Bookmarks, browser history, the back button, and the forward button can all be made to act as the user expects while enabling you to update only the part of the page that has changed.